# docker failing to bind to 127.0.0.1 if network driving is not host

Tags: docker

I have a python unittest code inside a `centos6.8` container. The unittest code needs to bind to 127.0.0.1.

This container is run with overlay network instead of host. The failure seems to go away if I switch `docker run` to `--network host`.

Inside the container I do see a loopback

```
[rtpbuild@bldrh6rtp89-rh6 /]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any suggestion on why binding to 127.0.0.1 doesn't work when overlay network is used but works when host network is used? And how can I make it work under overlay network?

Comment: Hey, the question isn't clear to me. Is it that the test is trying to connect to some other resource (like DB) on host machine? or is it something else?

Comment: @Shashank it's unittest code where it is creating a listener on 127.0.0.1 and connect to it and do some "unit test" (it isnt my code so i dont know exactly what it is testing for) but it is failing to bind to ip 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Should work, you need to elaborate a bit more how you run containers. As an example, docker swarm cluster, manager node, overlay network in swarm scope.

**Command**

```
docker run -it --rm --network ${network} -p 127.0.0.1:555:8080 caa06d9c/echo
```

**Request**

```
curl 127.0.0.1:555/
```

**Reply**

```
{
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/",
    "ip": "172.17.0.1"
}
```

**Command**

```
docker run -it --rm --network ${network} -p 127.0.0.1:555:8080 caa06d9c/echo --ip 127.0.0.1
```

**Check**

```
docker exec ${container} netstat -ptunl
```

**Result**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address State  PID/Program name
tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:8080 0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 1/python3
```

So Docker correctly assign interfaces and ports